# Application Not Debugging in Eclipse

Tags: java, debugging, oc4j

I am trying to run my Java application in debug mode in Eclipse, but it's not working. It was fine until yesterday when I could properly debug my application. I am able to run my application on the server ( Oracle OC4J Standalone Server 10.1.3) properly. Only while debugging, it continues for a long time and then shows a server time out error. I tried increasing the Server time out, but was of no use.

I also tried removing the Server and creating it again and restarting Eclipse. Is there something I could do about this?

Edit: Strack trace on trying to Run it as Remote Java Application

Exception Stack tace:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jdi.internal.connect.SocketTransportService$2.run(SocketTransportService.java:136)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an issue with OC4J's debug mode enabling. Sometimes I've noticed that after enabling it (via opmn.xml) it will work for a while then stop working. What I've found to actually work all the time is editing the /bin/oc4j.cmd file and adding the line:

```
set JVMARGS=-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=9009,suspend=y,server=y
```

then start a Remote debugging session from Eclipse on the port 9009

Comment: Since Im new to this could you tell me how to go about it? Shoud we modify the command script in the bin file by adding the line at the end? And how do we start the debuggin session on the port 9009? Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: Yes, modify that script file in your  OC4J intallation dir and add that line to it, then restart the server. Once that's done, right click your project in Eclipse ->Debug as... -> Debug configurations-> Double-click "Remote Java Application" on the left -> set 9009 for Port -> click Debug. It should connect and then show when a certain debug breakpoint was reached when the app was executed on the server.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it. Its throwing the following error:         Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused.

Comment: I have added the Exception Stack trace to my Question

Comment: When you start your OC4J does it say it's starting in debug mode?